# How is it that React allows $.ajax without requiring jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

In the React tutorial, I'm looking at the [`example.js`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/blob/master/public/scripts/example.js) file

The file gets comments from a server in this function:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
// Rest of CommentBox...
```

However, there is no `require('jquery')` in the code. React doesn't list jQuery as a dependency. When I search for `ajax` in the react repository there isn't any declaration of that function.

Is this `$.ajax` function a react-specific function? Is it something other than jQuery? Thanks for any help to better understand how this part of React works!

Comment: `$` is just a variable name, anyone can define it to be anything...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

React *DOES NOT* require jQuery to work. If you look at [this page from tutorial website](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#your-first-component)(scroll a bit above) it is clearly mentioned that jQuery is included only to simplify.

Including the note here too

> Note: We included jQuery here because we want to simplify the code of
>   our future ajax calls, but it's NOT mandatory for React to work.

Also [check out the complete section on getting started](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#getting-started) that has the main index html page which includes jQuery.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

its being required in the [`index.html`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/blob/master/public/index.html) file. youll notice it gets required before the example.js file, which means jquery is available by the time the react code gets executed